# How do you resolve Device not accepting address error 62?

Tags: usb, mount

I used my usb drive on a shared computer in my workplace that is very old (Window Vista old I think) and no connection to internet. It detected it but the files and directories are all in gibberish. The system showed a speech bubble suggesting me to plug it in a USB3.0 port (It's an observation. Not sure if it has anything to do with the corruption).

I later tried to plug it into my own desktop with Ubuntu 22.04. This is the output of `dmesg -w` after I plugged the drive in:

```
[  192.843271] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  192.872616] usb 2-9: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 0.02
[  192.872630] usb 2-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  192.872631] usb 2-9: Product: Mass Storage
[  192.872633] usb 2-9: Manufacturer: Generic
[  192.872633] usb 2-9: SerialNumber: 7ADD2ADF
[  192.887815] usb-storage 2-9:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  192.888170] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-9:1.0
[  192.888210] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  192.888983] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  193.915887] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  193.916111] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  193.917296] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] 245760000 512-byte logical blocks: (126 GB/117 GiB)
[  193.917424] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  193.917424] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  193.917546] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  193.919812]  sda: sda1
[  193.919892] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  226.610384] usb 2-9: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  226.637981] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=31s
[  226.637983] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0e a5 fe 00 00 00 70 00
[  226.637984] I/O error, dev sda, sector 245759488 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 14 prio class 2
[  226.643051] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  226.643053] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
[  226.643054] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[  226.643055] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0e a5 fe 78 00 00 80 00
[  226.643055] I/O error, dev sda, sector 245759608 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
[  226.643066] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 device offline or changed
[  226.643067] I/O error, dev sda, sector 245759752 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 15 prio class 2
[  228.261632]  sda: sda1
[  264.596814] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  269.972870] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  270.180699] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 7, error -62
[  275.604792] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  280.980782] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  281.188663] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 7, error -62
[  286.612573] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  291.992551] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  292.204450] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 7, error -62
[  297.620548] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  302.996598] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  303.204340] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 7, error -62
[  303.220435] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=74s
[  303.220436] usb 2-9: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  303.220437] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 02 28 00 01 f8 00
[  303.220438] I/O error, dev sda, sector 552 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 59 prio class 2
[  303.220499] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 60s
[  303.220553] device offline error, dev sda, sector 552 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  303.220556] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 65, async page read
[  308.628543] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  314.004124] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  314.211983] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[  319.635926] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  325.011506] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  325.219323] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 9, error -62
[  325.227374] usb usb2-port9: attempt power cycle
[  332.435116] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  337.810722] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  338.018709] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 10, error -62
[  343.442617] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  348.818355] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  349.026315] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 11, error -62
[  349.034410] usb usb2-port9: unable to enumerate USB device
[  354.450251] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  354.512915] audit: type=1107 audit(1702918847.813:122): pid=925 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/timedate1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.187" pid=3556 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=5844 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  359.825917] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  360.033835] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[  365.457621] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  370.833445] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  371.041553] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 13, error -62
[  371.049515] usb usb2-port9: attempt power cycle
[  378.257372] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  383.633165] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  383.841101] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 14, error -62
[  389.264995] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  394.644716] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  394.852775] usb 2-9: device not accepting address 15, error -62
[  394.860780] usb usb2-port9: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here and is there anyway to fix it? It would be nice to save the data inside but if it's not possible I want to at least format the drive. Many thanks!